# Function doesn't convert parentheses to minus

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import numeral from "numeral";

const value_regex = /(-?\d+,?\.?(\d+)?)+/;
const format_dec = "0.00";

const formatIssue = (value, format = "0,0.00") => {
  if (value) {
    try {
      return numeral(value).format(format);
    } catch (e) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return value;
};

function onValueChange(evt) {
  if (evt.target.value) {
    try {
      const numericValue = evt.target.value.match(value_regex)[0];

      console.log("value", formatIssue(numericValue, format_dec));
      return formatIssue(numericValue, format_dec);
    } catch (e) {
      return evt.target.value;
    }
  } else {
    return evt.target.value;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="text" name="name" onBlur={onValueChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to allow input to display values that regex match but is not doing that if values comes like ($200.00). If values comes like ($200.00) it should format to -200.00.
The issue is if it's possible to allow it doing that without changing 'value_regex'

```
(-?\d+,?\.?(\d+)?)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/l3gc3N/1

My code is:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-moon-1dz6n?file=/src/App.js:88-99

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted (or as a stack snippet, when applicable) - do not just dump it onto external platforms.

Comment: Essential info should not be behind links.

Comment: Your current regex allows any characters to come before the digits, and any after. Is that intended?

Comment: Thanks for providing more of the code (although a [runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) would be better -- what's `numera(...).format`? please stop nickle-and-diming). The chief issue I see above is that you're *returning* the formatted value from the handler, but nothing is going to use that return value to update the input. You have to do that in your handler. (The return value of an old-fashioned `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler is only used if it's `false` [it prevents the default action].)

Comment: @trincot if input has `asd445` it should convert to 445.00. The regex is matching that, so regex is ok.

Comment: Your current regex also allows expressions like "abc-1-73-1.1-5abc", from which it will extract "-1-73-1.1-5". That does not seem right though.

Comment: @trincot ok but in the input field if you type 'abc-1-73-1.1-5abc' the value printed is '1731.15' which is good.

Comment: Only is not able to convert ($200.00) to -200.00. So, brackets should be converted into minus

Comment: I don't know what `numeral` does, so I'll have to trust you on that ;-)

Comment: So also `1,.1` is not a problem?

Comment: Numeral will format the value: i.e 1000 => 10,000.0000

Comment: No, because if you see codesandbox, the value in console will be 1.10. which is good.

Comment: Yes, but you seem to suggest it will also clear the intermediate `-` signs in "-1-73-1.1-5". I mean, the regex is not clearing those. BTW: I am not looking at the sandbox. All necessary info should be here.

Comment: @trincot it's okay, only minus should be if input value is ($200). So, parentheses should be converted into minus '-200'.

Comment: So, why don't you want to change the regex? I mean, you do realise you need to spot those parentheses, ... so what method will you allow us to propose, if it is not your regex?

Comment: @trincot Because I'm losing matches. This regex is matching all what I need.

Comment: So you don't want us to propose a regex with which you will not lose matches? I don't get it.

Comment: @trincot maybe it's better to use another regex only for that issue with ($200) inside onValueChange change function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you write that you don't want the regex to be changed, I really think a change is called for.

Of course, it should not diminish any of its current functionality, and that you can achieve by using a pipe (`|`) followed by an alternative pattern.

So if we don't touch what is already in the regex, it would extend to this:

```
const value_regex = /(-?\d+,?\.?(\d+)?)+|\(\$?(\d+,?\.?(\d+)?)+\)/;
```

Although I would really want to change your currrent regex a bit -- but I leave that to you -- so that it would become:

```
const value_regex = /-?\d+[,.]?\d*|\(\$?\d+[,.]?\d*\)/;
```

...because:

- `(\d+)?` is really `\d*`, but without capture group (which you don't reference any way).
- I suspect that with `,?\.?` you really intended to say that the decimal separator can be *either* a comma or a point, while this would actually allow `,.` as well. So I would replace it with `[,.]?`.
- The outer `()+` would allow a number to have several `-` in them, and as many decimal separators, which is not really how we write numbers.

With either of these, you then just need to add this line to your code:

```
if (numericValue[0] === "(") numericValue = "-" + numericValue.slice(1);
```

If your regex is also used in other contexts, then just make this `value_regex` a local variable in your event handler. That way it will not affect any other dependencies.